# Where are bad men sent?

Tags: riddle

> I am usually grey and black,
>
> but with a tint of orange
>
> My inhabitants despise me,
>
> but my city loves me.

What am I?

I know that there are two possible answers for this, so I will give a hint as to which one it is:

> My cedslurbanm morf si pnosir
>
>  and my name is close to siphon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this

> Prison?

I am usually grey and black,

> The walls of the prison

but with a tint of orange

> The prisoners’ jumpsuits

My inhabitants despise me,

> Prisoners don’t like prison

but my city loves me.

> But the city likes to be safe and house criminals there

Hints:

> My cedslurbanm morf si pnosir = “My unscrambled form is prison” and my name is close to siphon = similar spelling I guess to prison.

Comment: That was fast... but good job!

Comment: @NotSp33dy The title was a pretty heavy giveaway from the beginning.

Comment: @BenBarden I couldn't think of anything. I tried publishing it last night, but I couldn't think of a title